# Find the flaw in this proof that $1$ is the greatest natural number

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification, fake-proofs, natural-numbers

[image]

I think the flaw is in assuming that $N^{2} \in \mathbb{N}$, but I don't know.

Comment: Since when is $N \geq N^2$ for $N \in \mathbb{N}$ ?

Comment: The flaw is in assuming that there is a largest positive integer.

Comment: @MattiP.: this follows from the hypothesis.

Comment: Where would $N+1$ fit into all of this? If $N \ge N+1$ then $0 \ge 1$ would be simpler contradiction.

Comment: @copper.hat: that's right. I guess that the goal is to make the proof cumbersome and divert attention so that the flaw is no immediately apparent.

Comment: Please edit your question tot property typeset the mathematics.  You may want to refer to the [MathJax guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on meta.

Comment: You have proven "if a largest natural number exists, then it is 1". This is because your first line says "let N be the largest natural number", but you have not shown its existence! Indeed, as one answerer says, you can use your (entirely correct) logic to contradict, thus showing there is no largest natural number

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The proof is logically correct, and leads to a contradiction (we know that $1<2$). Thus it is a valid proof that there is no greatest natural number.

Answer (score 2):

The flaw is in assuming there is a largest natural number. Assuming that, one can also show that number is $2$, or $17$, or $-3.5$, all at the same time. [Ex falso quodlibet](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion).